# Web2py request different behavior on local and online version (server code executes, but returns 404 error)

Tags: javascript, ajax, web2py

On my local version of the application, making the request with the following code, executes the code on the server, returning successfully.

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: "{{=URL('default', 'serverFunction.json')}}",
 data: {id: id}
});
```

However, if I make the request like so (without '.json' after serverFunction)

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: "{{=URL('default', 'serverFunction')}}",
 data: {id: id}
});
```

The server code executes, but returns a 404 error.

On the online version, it returns a 404 error in both cases, executing the server code.

Comment: `The extension .html is optional; .html is assumed as default. The extension determines the extension of the view that renders the output of the controller function f().` So in second case .html extension is assumed. I am not sure about this. Read [URL](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Dispatching)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `serverFunction` returns a dictionary, by default web2py will look for the associated /views/default/serverFunction.json view. If it does not exist, it may instead use the /views/generic.json view, but generic views are disabled by default. The scaffolding application includes the following line:

```
response.generic_patterns = ['*'] if request.is_local else []
```

which enables the generic views for local requests only. That is likely why your .json request works locally but not remotely. If you want to use the generic.json view, in the `serverFunction` function, you can simply include:

```
response.generic_patterns = ['json']
```

or:

```
response.view = 'generic.json'
```

It is not clear why you are getting a 404 error for local requests without the .json extension -- would have to see more code to help with that.

Comment: I put `response.generic_patterns = ['json']` on the beginning of all *.py files that include some sort of functions related to ajax calls and it seems to solve the problem on server side